# Outputs not displaying when using modules

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a `outputs.tf` file under my module directory. And I have a `Main.tf` file. When I create a resource and Terraform Apply, the outputs does not display. However, if I don't use modules and create my resources strictly from the `Main.tf` file, the outputs shows fine. Is there any different I need to do for my outputs to display when using modules and a separate `outputs.tf` file?

```
    Terraform v0.11.14
+ provider.aws v2.19.0
```

However, if I don't use modules and create my resources strictly from the `Main.tf` file, the outputs shows fine.

#### main.tf

```
module "identity-provider" {
  source = "./modules/identity-provider"
}



module "saml-role1" {
  source = "./modules/saml-roles/"
}
```

===============

#### module file

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role1" {
  name                 = "saml-role1"
  description          = "Blah Blah"
  path                 = "/"
  assume_role_policy   = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json}"
  permissions_boundary = ""
  max_session_duration = 43200



resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "Read-Only" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.role1.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
}
```

=================

#### outputs.tf

```
output "Role1-ARN" {
  value = "${module.saml-role1.arn}"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Only the outputs of the root module are captured and displayed by Terraform.  If you need to pass outputs from a module to the root module you have to do it explicitly (e.g. you do not have access to all the resources created by a module from the root ONLY the values specified as outputs).  If you include an output in your module file like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role1" {
  name                 = "saml-role1"
  description          = "Blah Blah"
  path                 = "/"
  assume_role_policy   = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json}"
  permissions_boundary = ""
  max_session_duration = 43200



resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "Read-Only" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.role1.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
}

output "saml-role1-arn" {
    value = "aws_iam_role.role1.arn"
}
```

Then from within the root module you can access the output:

```
module "saml-role1" {
  source = "./modules/saml-roles/"
}

output "saml-role1-arn" {
    value = "${module.saml-role1.saml-role1-arn}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need an another output.tf file along with your main.tf file to capture the output from your module.

Below is the content of the output.tf file.

```
output "Role1-ARN" {
  value = "${module.saml-role1.Role1-ARN}"
}
```

Regards,

Vinoth

Answer (score 0):

When you are keeping 'count' variable in your module, then you need to use * in outputs.tf file.

Example:

```
output "Role1-ARN" {
  value = "${module.saml-role1.*.Role1-ARN}"
}
```